# How to disable a display which doesn't exist?

Tags: linux, external-display

My problem is that my laptop's screen is broken, so I use an external monitor to play some games on Linux. I have an AOC International 15. But, according to my laptop, there is a third external display, which doesn't even exist. How to remove it?

Answer (score 0):

You could try it with xrandr. First type
`xrandr` into your terminal. You'll see a list of all your video outputs and their configurations. Look for your notebooks display (mine is called eDP but yours may be different) and type in `xrandr --output eDP --off` (or whatever xrandr calls your notebooks display).